# PHP Object Oriented array not being printed

Tags: php, oop

Alright so I got 2 problems on my hands at the moment and those are

- I want to call the function from the parent object but I am getting a lot of errors saying "Fatal error: Cannot instantiate abstract class Person"
- If I call the getUserItems directly it will not do anything. There wont be anything echoed or such.

```
<?php

    abstract class Person {
        abstract function getUserItems();
    }

    class inventory extends Person {

        protected $storage = array();
        protected $item_id;

        public function itemAdd($itemname) {
            $storage[$this->item_id+1] = $itemname;
        }

        public function getUserItems() {
            foreach($this->storage as $itemName=>$item_id) {
                echo $itemName." ".$item_id."<br/>";
            }
        }
    }

    $user = new Person();

    $user->getUserItems();

    /*$user = new inventory();
    $user->itemAdd("Item 1");
    $user->itemAdd("Item 2");

    $user->getUserItems();*/

?>
```

Comment: You're trying to create an instance of Person (`new Person()`). But the Class "person" is declared as "abstract". Remove the "abstract" and it should work,.

Comment: `Fatal error: Cannot instantiate abstract class Person` is very clear. ` $user = new Person();` is wrong. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OOP - abstract class [may not be instantiated](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php).

> [An abstract class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761194/interface-vs-abstract-class-general-oo) is a class with both implementation and interface (pure virtual methods) that will be inherited. Interfaces generally do not have any implementation but only pure virtual functions.

So you cannot instantiate (`new Person()`). You must extend this abstract class and implement it's abtract functions (same way you did in inventory).

Regarding the `echo`ing problem - inside your `itemAdd` function you didn't use the object's `$storage` member (you just used a local `$storage` variable). You should use it as the object's memebr, using `$this->storage`:

```
public function itemAdd($itemname) {
    $this->storage[$this->item_id+1] = $itemname;
}
```

> Note that I'm not so sure how you managed the `$this->item_id` member because you didn't set/changed it in the code.

If you only want to add new items to the `storage` member you could use:

```
$this->storage[] = $itemname;
```

This will make sure every new item will be added to the `$storage` array.

Comment: Yes but how do I assign every one of them to an id? Thats why I used $this->item_id

Comment: If each of them have a specific `id` you can use `itemAdd($item_id, $item_name) ` and inside the function to use the `$item_id`.

Comment: Hmm yeah I get that, but for example if I wanted to use $person->getUserItems() how do I achieve it? For example if I use person extends inventory I will get an error saying that it cannot find that class etc.
Example code: http://pastebin.com/ni3QMdtD

Comment: You ask a different question here (and I'm not so sure I understand what you ask). Meanwhile - if the answer is correct (based on your original question) you should accept it. And try to clarify your question so I might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

ad1)

Person is abstract class so you can not create object of that class.

ad2)

You must use `$this`

so not:

```
 $storage[$this->item_id+1]
```

but

```
$this->storage[++$this->item_id]
```

Here I fixed another bug which was $this->item_id+1

Answer (score 0):

Abstract class can not access directly but access from other class.

```
abstract class Person {
    abstract function getUserItems();
}

class inventory extends Person {

    protected $storage = array();
    protected $item_id=2;

    public function itemAdd($itemname) {
        $storage[$this->item_id+1] = $itemname;
    }

    public function getUserItems() {
        foreach($this->storage as $itemName=>$item_id) {
            echo $itemName." ".$item_id."<br/>";
        }
    }
}

$user = new inventory();

$user->getUserItems();

$user = new inventory();
$user->itemAdd("Item 1");
$user->itemAdd("Item 2");

$user->getUserItems();
```